# How to run a server in background with CircleCI?

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, circleci

I am using CircleCI with my Django project. I want to run a server (specifically `python manage.py runserver`) in the background for some specific selenium tests.

My `config.yml` is somewhat like

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.1-browsers
      - image: selenium/standalone-chrome

    working_directory: ~/myproject

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt

      - run:
          name: run unit tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test

      - run:
          name: run selenium tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py migrate
            python manage.py runserver 8000 
            python manage.py run_selenium_tests
```

I could make it work by running selenium tests inside django `LiveServerTestCase`. But I want to run selenium tests independently, for that I need runserver to be running in the background. Right now circleci stops execution at `python manage.py runserver` and eventually timeouts. Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start the server as a [background command](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#background-commands). Optionally, you can also use cURL to wait for the server to be ready.

Based on the config you posted, you could do something like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.1-browsers
      - image: selenium/standalone-chrome

    working_directory: ~/myproject

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt

      - run:
          name: run unit tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test

      - run:
          name: run selenium tests prep
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py migrate
      - run:
          name: run server
          command: python manage.py runserver 8000
          background: true
      - run:
          name: run selenium tests
          command: |
            curl --retry-delay 5 --retry 10  --retry-connrefused http://localhost:8000
            python manage.py run_selenium_tests
```

The curl statement waits for the port to respond before continuing. This gives time for your server to fully start up.

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: When I tried this I was getting this error `curl: option --retry-connrefused: is unknown`. But worked when i removed `curl`. Thanks!

Comment: I had to use `sleep 5` before `curl`, otherwise it would fail with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`

Comment: Hi Richard, would you suggest another way to try a server until the connection is successful? I am using CircleCI and curl also fails.

Comment: Try Dockerize: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/prevent-race-conditions-by-waiting-for-services-with-dockerize/11215?u=felicianotech

Comment: In case the --retry-connrefused "seems" ignored, for instance in a docker container, try adding the "-4" option which makes curl use IPv4. See here: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5080

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CircleCI, but the problem is that `manage.py runserver` is blocking, i.e. - it does not run in the background. According to the CircleCI documentation you can daemonize a process:

https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/background-process/

As to whether you will be able to hit the port after that (will CI allow you to bind to a port?), I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work with gunicorn. Here is the `config.yml`

```
  # run tests!
  - run:
      name: run unittests
      command: |
        . venv/bin/activate
        python manage.py test
        python manage.py migrate

  - run:
      name: run server in background
      command: |
        . venv/bin/activate
        gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 --pid=gunicorn.txt --daemon
      background: true

  - run:
      name: run selenium test
      command: |
        . venv/bin/activate
        python manage.py run_selenium_tests
        kill -9 `cat gunicorn.txt`
```